# Given a representation of $su(3)$ labelled by $(p, q)$, is there a way to construct its state of greatest weight?

Tags: symmetry, representation-theory, lie-algebra

My current understanding of the representations of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ is as follows:

We can construct 3 $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ subalgebras with step operators $I_\pm, U_\pm, V_\pm$. These maybe be expressed in terms of $I_3$ and $Y$, which are proportional to two simultaneously diagonalised Gell-Mann matrices. States are given by points in the $(I_3, Y)$ plane and we move between states using the step operators. $I_+$ for instance is a step $(1, 0)$.

We may label a representation by $(p, q)$ where $p$ is the number of times $I_-$ may be applied to the state of greatest weight before it vanishes, and similarly q is the number of times $U_-$ may be applied to the state of greatest weight before it vanishes. Through commutation relations of the step operators, we find that the states form a hexagon with alternating sides of length $p$ and $q$. Thus we need the $(I_3, Y)$ coordinates of a single state in order to draw the whole lattice.

[image: states in a representation of su(3)]

Additionally, there is an axis of symmetry about the $Y$ axis from which we get the $I_3$ coordinate of the state of greatest weight $M$ as $p/2$. Is it possible to find the $Y$ coordinate of $M$ in a similar manner ?

As an example, the lattice given by the (2, 1) representation, with circles indicating degenerate states:
[image: 15 states]

I would deduce the $I_3$ value for the top-right state to be 1, so that the top row is $(-1, Y_\text{greatest}), \; (0, Y_\text{greatest}),\; (1, Y_\text{greatest})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the formal Lie-algebraic statement you are seeking, but the practical seat-of-the-pants answer is evident: The origin of your Y here (in your normalization it is strangeness), that is, the line of zero Y is *not* the geometric center of your diagram, but the isoquartet line connecting the vertices defining the widest part of your diamond.

For the formal answer, see [this](http://jde27.uk/lgla/33_classification_accessible.html).

Here, you are plotting the D(2,1) deciquintet, with one antiquark and two quarks, whose Young tableau looks like a pistol.

[image: 15]

(Weight diagram from [here](http://mf23.web.rice.edu/LA_8_v2.2%20Highest%20weight%20representations.pdf). I-spin blue, U-spin green. The inner states are doubled.)

The top line is the isotriplet  $\bar s dd, \bar s du, \bar s uu$.

The second line is the origin of *Y*, with no strangeness. It consists of an isoquartet spanning the edges of the diamond, mentioned above,
$\bar u dd, (\bar u u- \bar d d)d, (\bar u u- \bar d d) u  , \bar d uu$ with the isodoublet $(\bar u u+ \bar d d)d, (\bar u u+ \bar d d) u$ collocated with the inner states of the above isoquartet. The origin of axes is empty of states.

The third line, of Y=-1, strangeness -1, consists of an isotriplet
$\bar u  ds,   (\bar u u- \bar d d) s, \bar d  us$
with an isosinglet  $(\bar u u+ \bar d d)s$ superposed on its central state. (So the three inner states form a triangle resting on its tip.)

The fourth line, on the southern border, is the obvious isodoublet
$\bar u ss, \bar d ss$.

This comprises the 15 states of D(2,1).   Y and I3 are motivated by strangeness physics, so the diamond is oriented "unnaturally", as you chose, and  its origin for them  is *not* a barycenter or something! From the convexity of these weight diagrams, it appears sensible to place the origin of Ys in the middle of the isomultiplet with the greatest width: Here, on the 2nd line; or, for the baryon decouplet D(3,0) on the top line, etc...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added lattice points. I hadn't chosen any representation in particular. I understand the origin for most representations is empty of states, which is why I was trying to go about finding a way to plot states in the ($I_3, Y$) plane. I had understood the $I_3=0$ line to be an axis of symmetry, is this correct ?

Comment: Correct; but *Y* =0 is not an axis of symmetry. Strangeness is an excessively physics, weird coordinate. Normally, the origin of Y is on the longest isomultiples axis.